# Autocomplete is not working on web but works in localhost

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdo

I have an Autocomplete function using php for queries and ajax , its work from localhost but when i upload to web, it wont work, this is my code. thank you

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  
  //autocomplete
  $(".auto").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 1
  });       

});
$(function() {
  
  //autocomplete
  $(".auto1").autocomplete({
    source: "search1.php",
    minLength: 1
  });       

});
$(function() {
  
  //autocomplete
  $(".auto2").autocomplete({
    source: "search2.php",
    minLength: 1
  });       

});
</script>
```

this is my query from database

```html
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'jobs');


if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT employee_name FROM employer WHERE employee_name LIKE :term');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));
        
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['employee_name'];
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }


    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}


?>
```

thanks for the help

Comment: I am sure no hosting would allow empty password. Double check your database credentials.

Comment: You need to update your database credentials to production values.  Don't you get errors when you try to establish connection to your database?

Comment: OMG! it works. i forgot to change the database credentials. My Bad. Thank you